# Python how to pick item from list containing lists

Tags: python, random, pygame

I have a problem with generating map. It uses several lists which contain list of vectors. There is also list of lists of wall set(which set represent maze in place pointed by vector). So I have problem with random. When I pick random item from list of mazes. Program is going crazy, and creates something which doesn't make much sense. I tried to pick manually each maze and it worked perfectly. I tried to find solution to this problem but there wasn't answer for this kind of problem. There is definitelly something wrong with taking random item from list of mazes in this loop.`
EDIT: Here is program which can be run to see results.

```
import pygame, random, sys

WIDTH= 640
HEIGHT = 480
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (50, 50, 255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(WHITE)

wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()





class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x





def ran_map():
    walls_1 = [ [0, 0, 40, 20],
                 [60, 0, 30, 20],
                 [0, 40, 40, 10],
                 [60, 40, 30, 10]
                 ]
    walls_2 = [ [0, 0, 60, 10],
                 [40, 10, 20, 10],
                 [0, 30, 20, 20],
                 [20, 40, 70, 10],
                 [80, 0, 10, 40]
                 ]
    walls_3 = [ [0, 0, 10, 50],
                 [10, 0, 80, 10],
                 [80, 10, 10, 40],
                 [30, 30, 30, 20]
                 ]
s_maze = [walls_1, walls_2, walls_3]

vectors = [[60, 60], [170, 60], [380, 60], [490, 60], [60, 370], [170, 370], [380, 370], [490, 370]]

for item in vectors:
    v1 = item[0]
    v2 = item[1]
    random_item = random.choice(s_maze)
    for item in random_item:
        w1 = item[0]
        w2 = item[1]
        s1 = w1+ v1
        s2 = w2+ v2
        wall = Wall(s1, s2, item[2], item[3])
        wall_list.add(wall)
        all_sprite_list.add(wall)



def xz():
    done = False
    while not done:
        pygame.init()
        clock.tick(45)
        ran_map()
        all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
    pygame.quit()

def main():
    xz()

main()
```

Comment: What exactly happens that shouldn't happen? If you get an error post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Can you please tell what do you mean by program picks something crazy? What do you mean by manually picking ?

Comment: You are using `item` for two different things which clobbers the first value.

Comment: what do you mean with "When I pick random item from list of mazes. Program is going crazy, and creates something which doesn't make much sense"? `random_item = random.choice(s_maze)` itself works good (random pick a wall)

Comment: Yes so starting off there is no error. It goes and generate that field but there is a maze which was not designed to be there. If i do not use random choice from list of walls and simply put last for loop with manually picked maze from list and then it is drawn as it was supposed to in each field pointed by vector. I tried with using in first loop item and in the next simply i and it did not help. If necessary i can put larger code which can be run and see results.

Answer (score 0):

The "going crazy" is most likely due to this duplicated iteration variable:

```
for *item* in vectors:
    ...
    for *item* in random_item:
```

I suggest you simplify the middle section of your code as follows:

```
...

mazes = {  # a dictionary of mazes
    'walls_1': [ [0, 0, 40, 20],
                 [60, 0, 30, 20],
                 [0, 40, 40, 10],
                 [60, 40, 30, 10]
               ],
    'walls_2': [ [0, 0, 60, 10],
                 [40, 10, 20, 10],
                 [0, 30, 20, 20],
                 [20, 40, 70, 10],
                 [80, 0, 10, 40]
               ],
    'walls_3': [ [0, 0, 10, 50],
                 [10, 0, 80, 10],
                 [80, 10, 10, 40],
                 [30, 30, 30, 20]
               ]
}

vectors = [[60, 60], [170, 60], [380, 60], [490, 60], [60, 370], [170, 370], [380, 370], [490, 370]]

for v1, v2 in vectors:
    random_item = random.choice(list(mazes.values()))

    for w1, w2, w3, w4 in random_item:
        s1 = w1 + v1
        s2 = w2 + v2
        wall = Wall(s1, s2, w3, w4)
        wall_list.add(wall)
        all_sprite_list.add(wall)

...
```